# How to use the default argument in a function?

Tags: c++

I have a function that has 2 optional parameters.
Sometimes I need only the 2nd parameter.

declaration:

```
void function(int a = 0, int b = 0);
```

call with 1st parameter:

```
function(10);
```

call with 2nd parameter only:

```
function(??,10);
```

How can I make the 2nd call valid?
The only way to do this, as far as I know, would be to use the default argument as the first variable, but there has to be something better.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: "Sometimes I need only the 2nd parameter." --> reverse parameter order if "Sometimes I need only the 1st parameter." is false.

Comment: You can only use the default values for the parameters at the end of the parameter list.

Comment: I understand, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to do this the plain way, however you could use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) which will behave very close:

```
#include <optional>

void function(std::optional<int> optional_a = {}, std::optional<int> optional_b = {}) {
    auto a = optional_a.value_or(0);
    auto b = optional_b.value_or(0);
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

calling the function now like this:

```
function();
function(5);
function({}, 10);
```

will give this output:

```
0 0
5 0
0 10
```

---

however there are two inconveniences:  you will need to introduce temporaries, and the caller doesn't know what the default value will be judging from the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like that. Only the last n parameters can be left default but all the parameters before those must be passed. You can only call it like so:
`function(0, 10)`